# OpenMP nested strange behaviour

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am investigating the behaviour of nested parallalization using openMP and I came across this issue that I find very hard to explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main (){
    int N = 3;
    int i,j; 
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {
    omp_set_nested(1); 
    #pragma omp for private(j) 
    for(i = 0; i<N; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<N; j++){
            printf("AAAAA ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The correct printout for the above program is

```
AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA
AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA 
AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA
```

but occasionally it will print out

```
AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA
AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA
AAAAA AAAAA
```

or some other configuration. I was thinking that this has to do with how 'i' is shared across the threads, but I haven't been able to find how this is handled explicitly by omp when using nested loops. Why does this happen?

Comment: Note: you do **not** have nested OpenMP loops in your code.

Comment: @Zulan Do you mean that I do not have a nested OMP loop, but rather a nested loop that is parallellized using OMP? Also, thanks that looks like what I need!

Comment: @Zulan means there is no nested parallelism. There is only a single omp parallel executed in the whole code.